# Pandas: rank after groupby using minrank

Tags: python, r, pandas, pandas-groupby

I know the `rank` method exists in `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, but I was wondering If I can use the *min* `rank` method to get the same result as in the `R` programming language for the following problem.

The dataset copied to my github is a few MB.

My attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

flights = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/nycflights13.csv?raw=true')
print(flights.shape)


df = (flights[flights.tailnum.notna()]
      .assign( on_time = lambda x: x.arr_time.notna() & (x.arr_delay <=0))
      .groupby('tailnum')['on_time']
      .agg([np.mean,'count',pd.Series.rank(method='min')]) # R uses min_rank
      .set_axis(['on_time','n','rank'],axis=1,inplace=False)
      .query( 'rank == 1.0')
     )

df.head()
```

It gives an error.

**Required output**

```
shape= 336776, 19

HEAD
tailnum on_time n
N121DE  0   2
N136DL  0   1
N143DA  0   1
N17627  0   2
N240AT  0   5
N26906  0   1

TAIL
tailnum on_time n
N939DN  0   1
N943DN  0   1
N953FR  0   3
N960DN  0   3
N965DN  0   2
N978SW  0   1
```

**R code works perfectly, but I want to use Pandas**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

df = flights %>%
  filter(!is.na(tailnum)) %>%
  mutate(on_time = !is.na(arr_time) & (arr_delay <= 0)) %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(on_time = mean(on_time), n = n()) %>%
  filter(min_rank(on_time) == 1)


dim(flights)
head(df)
tail(df)
```

Help is appreciated.

Related links:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html

Comment: I wonder if translating from dplyr/httr syntax to python syntax might be more difficult than translating from base R, although that's just speculation.

Comment: @42- Yeah, its not so straight forward, I was able to translate almost all other things except than `min_rank` in this code. If you are familiar with pandas, help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not, hence my caveats. I was able to read most python in the past, but your use of "dot"-functions without parentheses may be n indication that some one or some group has created a python syntax dual to R's httr syntax. In which case I thank you for the education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R's dplyr, the [`min_rank`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html) is not an aggregated function but a calculation *after* aggregation (actually inspired by the ANSI SQL 2003 window function, `RANK () OVER ()` which also is not an aggregate function). Therefore, add such a calculated column in the Pandas data frame *after* aggregation not inside `agg()`. Then call `reindex` or `drop` to exclude the helper column:

```
df = (flights[flights.tailnum.notna()]
      .assign( on_time = lambda x: x.arr_time.notna() & (x.arr_delay <=0))
      .groupby('tailnum')['on_time']
      .agg([np.mean, 'count'])
      .set_axis(['on_time','n'],axis=1, inplace=False)
      .assign(rank = lambda x: pd.Series.rank(x['on_time'], method='min'))
      .query("rank == 1") 
      .reindex(columns=['on_time', 'n']) # OR .drop(columns=['rank'])
     )

print(flights.shape)
# (336776, 19)

print(df.head())
#          on_time  n
# tailnum
# N121DE       0.0  2
# N136DL       0.0  1
# N143DA       0.0  1
# N17627       0.0  2
# N240AT       0.0  5

print(df.tail())
#          on_time  n
# tailnum
# N943DN       0.0  1
# N953FR       0.0  3
# N960DN       0.0  3
# N965DN       0.0  2
# N978SW       0.0  1
```

Comment: Thank a lot. You saved my time. All day today I was looking SO question how to figure out this problem. Finally, a golden angel helped me out.

Comment: No problem. Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!